# Flutter: How to insert items into a list of Map at any Index?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a FireStore collection named "products" and in there I have documents consisting of product data such as name, price, and category. It follows the structure like this

```
      {
 "name": "Milk Shake Strawberry",
 "price": "250",
 "category": "Drinks",
 "categoryID:1234},
  {
 "name": "Swiss Roll",
 "price": "150",
 "category": "Cake",
 "categoryID":1235}
```

I map all the product data to ProductItemData using the following code,

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>?>? productItemsData = snapshots.data?.docs
                          .map((e) => e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?)
                          .toList();
```

Then I have the category data like this.

```
   {
 "index": "0",
 "categoryName": "Drinks",
 "categoryID:1234
   },{
    "index": "1",
 "categoryName": "Cake",
 "categoryID":1235}
```

And I Map all the category data using the following code

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>?>?  categoryData= snapshotCat.data?.docs
                 .map((e) => e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?)
                 .toList();
```

Then I use two for loops to insert index into the productItemData. The code follows like this.

```
          for (var doc in categoryData!) {
                                  Map<String, dynamic> data = doc as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                  for (var product in productItemsData!) {
                                    Map<String, dynamic> productData = product as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                    if (productData["category"] == data["name"]) {
                                      sortedProductItemsData?.insert(data["index"], productData);
                                      break;
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
```

I have declared a new sortedProductItemsData List to store this data.

Now the issue is when there is an index which try to insert to sortedProductItemsData, has a greater index than the items length of sortedProductItemsData .

Ex: Index 1 category "index" value will be added along with the respective productdata. Same with the 2nd item.But now if we have "index:8" string to insert to the List , following error comes

```
Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..5: 8
```

I think it's because sortedProductItemsData List has 2 items in index 0 and index 1, and now we try to add another item at index 8.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: hmmm on the **data["name"]** i think no one will match this since on the other list it's 
**categoryName** so it should be called **data["categoryName"]** then for sortedProductItemsData rather insert just use normal add when all data been added you can sort the list afterward by price or name e.g. **sortedProductItemsData.sort((a,b)
=> a["price"].compareTo(b["price"]));** something like this

Comment: can you try adding `if (index >= 0 && index <= sortedProductItemsData.length) {
        sortedProductItemsData?.insert(index, productData);
      }` ?

Comment: @Arbiter Chil
It is matching fine as long as there are products more than the number of categories.